# Trying to use limit with variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying this code to use LIMIT in MYSQL with a variable. When I use a simple number for LIMIT it works fine but when I use a variable then it's not working.

```
SET @increment:=9;
SET @number:=1;
SET @end:=10*@number;
SET @start:=@end-@increment;

SELECT name, detail FROM tab1 LIMIT @start, @end;
```

When I use the below code (no variable) it works fine:

```
SELECT name, detail FROM tab1 LIMIT 0,10;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm using in this way. Maybe it'll help you.

```
SET @increment := 4;
SET @number := 1;
SET @end := 5 * @number;
SET @start := @end - @increment;


PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT @i := total, user FROM logintable LIMIT ?,?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @start, @end;

SELECT @i AS result;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only way to achieve it.

Comment: @Constantin Actually there is another way too: instead of using [_user-defined_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) variables, you can declare [_local variables_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) using `DECLARE` statement. Variables declared in such way can be used with the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The values need to be constant.

According to the spec:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: then how to get the specific record from database through variable